# Raspberry pi 4 to arduino via usb Serial for robot car

Tags: python, c++, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am trying to code a line follower car using a Raspberry Pi with camera, Arduino and an l298n motor driver. I am trying have the Raspberry Pi communicate with the Arduino using USB serial and I am struggling a bit.

Here is the code I have for the Arduino:

```cpp
#define leftEnable 6    // EnA
#define leftReverse 8   // IN1
#define leftForward 9   // IN2
#define rightEnable 5   //EnB
#define rightReverse 11 //IN4
#define rightForward 10 //IN3

void setup() { // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(leftEnable, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rightEnable, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(leftReverse, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rightReverse, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(leftForward, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rightForward, OUTPUT);

  // Configure for forward direction only
  digitalWrite(leftReverse, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rightReverse, LOW);
  digitalWrite(leftForward, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rightForward, HIGH);
}

void loop() { // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  analogWrite(leftEnable, 255);
  analogWrite(rightEnable, 255);
  delay(1000);

  // Slow down
  analogWrite(leftEnable, 200);
  analogWrite(rightEnable, 200);
  delay(1000);

  //stop
  analogWrite(leftEnable, 0);
  analogWrite(rightEnable, 0);
  delay(2000);

  //turn right
  analogWrite(leftEnable, 255);
  analogWrite(rightEnable, 0);
  delay(1000);

  analogWrite(leftEnable, 0);
  analogWrite(rightEnable, 255);
  delay(1000);
}
```

And for the Raspberry:

```py
import serial
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
from picamera import PiCamera

with PiCamera() as src:
 src.resolution = (640,480)
 src.framerate = 20
 src.shutter_speed = 75000
 output = np.empty((480,640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

 while(True):
 start_time = time.time()
 src.capture(output, format='bgr', use_video_port=True)
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(output, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 gray[gray < 50] =0
 gray[gray > 50] = 255
 top_center = np.average(np.where(gray[0] ==0 ))
 bottom_center = np.average(np.where(gray[-1] ==0))

 if top_center - bottom_center > 25:
 print("Turn right")
 elif top_center - bottom_center <-25:
 print("Turn left")
 else:
 print("Stay on course")

 cv2.imshow('Output', output)
 key = cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF

 if key==ord("q"):
 break

 cv2.waitKey(8)
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Tip: Remove all the extraneous blank lines. It makes your code scroll and a lot harder to understand.

Comment: *"I am struggling a bit"* is not a question. What are you struggling with? What is the code doing? What do you expect the code to do? Please read the [help] pages and take the [tour] to see how to write a good question for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing with serial ports commands on both ends.
Send commands to serial port like this on raspberry pi

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 19200
ser.port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
ser.write(b'L') # send codes like 'L' for left,;'R' for Right
```

Read commands on arduino like this

```
void setup() {
  // initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    if (Serial.read() == 'L'){
      // write code for left turn
    }
  }
}
```